# Querying complex json

Tags: javascript, json, filter, indexof

I have JSON that has to conform to this standard.

```
{
  "level": [
    {
      "1": {
        "Title": "My First Title",
        "Body": "My First Body"
      }
    },
    {
      "2": {
        "Title": "My Second Title",
        "Body": "My Second Body"
      }
    }
}
```

Whilst I know it's not the best formed JSON in the world, it has to stay like this for integration into a complex system. I have not been successful in finding a way of querying everything inside the "first level". I only need to ever strip the json by the "1", "2", "3", keys.

The SQL equivilant would be:

```
SELECT Title, Body FROM level WHERE level.id = 1.
```

I'm struggling because there is no id. the key is the id therefore I do not know what to search on.

Returned JSON should be:

```
{
    "Title": "My First Title",
    "Body": "My First Body"
}
```

Comment: `json.level[0]["1"].Title`

Comment: @adeneo but first he would have to search the object `level[0]` for the key `"1"`.

Answer (score 1):

This will return an `Array` with matches:

```
var queryID = "1";

yourJSON.level.filter(function(row){ return queryID in row; })
```

Comment: In the OP's situation probably more to-the-point than my alternative. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you brought up SQL... You could use [linq.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

```
var data = {
  "level": [
    {
      "1": {
        "Title": "My First Title",
        "Body": "My First Body"
      }
    }, {
      "2": {
        "Title": "My Second Title",
        "Body": "My Second Body"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Now, for example:

```
var result = Enumerable.From(data.level)
    .Where("$.hasOwnProperty(1)")
    .FirstOrDefault(null);

result;
// {"1":{"Title":"My First Title","Body":"My First Body"}}
```

or

```
var result = Enumerable
    .From(data.level)
    .Select(function ($) {
        var keys = Object.keys($);
        return {
            id: keys[0],
            value: $[keys[0]]
        };
    })
    .Where("$.id == 1")
    .Select("$.value")
    .FirstOrDefault(null);

result; 
// {"Title":"My First Title","Body":"My First Body"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want all of that as an array of objects:

```
var levels = [];
json["level"].forEach(function (val) {
      Object.keys(val).forEach(function (key) {
          levels[key] = val[key];
      });
});
```

now if you query level[id] you should get the desired result.

See this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/c2vk5c6m/